# How JavaScript stores variables in call stack

Tags: javascript, memory-management

call stack is used to push and pop functions when they are invoked and returned but what I really want to understand is weather the variables are placed on the top of call stack as soon as the script is loaded or they are placed inside of stack as the JavaScript engine go through the script line by line. 
Thank You.

Comment: What if I tell you they even end up on the heap (sometimes)? Why exactly do you want to know this (cause this is a very complex topic, I could write a book about it [and it would be bad])

Comment: how could this be done "as soon as the script is loaded"? JS is a dynamic language, it's impossible to tell statically which functions are going to be called at what times and with what arguments.

Comment: @JonasWilms First of all thank you for considering my question and what I meant by variables is primitive but my bad. I'm actually trying to learn deeply that how JavaScript works behind the scenes, is there any resource that you can share so that I could get my Job done?

Comment: @RobinZigmond, Thank You for responding to my question, actually I have just started learning JavaScript and have plenty of questions inside my head. If you can share some good resources to make my journey a bit easy, I'll be thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

It's the second one.
Because Javascript is a dynamic language, it doesn't deal with function invocations until it runs through the script line by line, at which point it will push them to the call stack.

Comment: this is oversimplified and that's not really how it works ... but I guess it's still the best answer we can give the OP (at the moment)